# Display Array Keys and Values to Table with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to export my array data from our org's API to the table but it doesn't like what my desired result, I'm struggling for hours and almost a day now. Here is my array sample:

```
Array (
[BASIC INCOME] => Array
(
    [RADIATOR] => 61154
    [METAL FABRICATION] => 41714
)
 [OT PAY] => Array
(
    [RADIATOR] => 35492.58
    [METAL FABRICATION] => 42670.81
)
)
```

Here is what I've tried now,

```
$j = 0;

foreach($summer as $key=>$val){

    $r = 0;
    
    foreach(array_keys($summer) as $gl_account){  
         
        ?>
        
    <tr>
        <td><?=array_keys($val)[$j]?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?=$gl_account?></td>
        <td><?=$summer[$sum]['BASIC INCOME']?></td>
        <td><?=$summer[$sum]['OT PAY']?></td>
        <td><?=$val[array_keys($val)[$j]]?></td>
        <td><?=$val[array_keys($val)[$j]]?></td>
        <td><?=$summer[$sum]['OT PAY']?></td>
        <td><?=$summer[$sum]['OT PAY']?></td>
        <td><?=$summer[$sum]['OT PAY']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $r++;} ?>
<?php $j++; }} ?>
```

Here is my desired result:

[image]

Maybe I have to format this array? In order to do it, I also need to use array manipulation which is also my problem. Thanks for the help...

Comment: It looks like you should transpose the array first. Then you can loop over it to generate the table you want.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610114/transpose-a-php-multidimensional-array-with-predefined-keys) for how to transpose associative arrays.

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't seem to have a direct relationship between your sample input and your exact desired output. I'm not sure if you need transposition or pivoting or both. Related content: [Display PHP multidimensional array in html table with each subarray in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5185670/2943403)

Comment: yeahh so hard to format that data into table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with mapping it to table, it's messy but it works,

```
 $i = 0;
foreach($summer as $key=>$val){
   $j = 0;
   foreach(array_keys($summer) as $gl_account){ ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?=array_keys($val)[$i]?></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><?=$gl_account?></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><?=number_format($summer[$gl_account][array_keys($val)[$i]] * 0.32, 2)?></td>
           <td><?=number_format($summer[$gl_account][array_keys($val)[$i]] * 0.20, 2)?></td>
           <td><?=number_format($summer[$gl_account][array_keys($val)[$i]] * 0.20, 2)?></td>
           <td><?=number_format($summer[$gl_account][array_keys($val)[$i]] * 0.26, 2)?></td>
           <td><?=number_format($summer[$gl_account][array_keys($val)[$i]] * 0.02, 2)?></td>
     </tr>
   <?php $j++;} ?>
<?php $i++; }} ?>
```